# obtener el numero menor y mayor de un elemnto de una array multidimencional

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs

tengo el siguiente array multidimencional y deseo obtener el numero menor y el numero mayor del campo n_comp y agregar  ambos valores al indice 0 de cada grupo de mi array.

```
    [
  [
    {
      "l_grupo": "F003",
      "total": 543
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "45",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "375.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "46",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "52.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "47",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "116.0000000"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "l_grupo": "B003",
      "total": 406
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "21",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "35.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "18",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "88.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "15",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "93.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "16",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "112.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "17",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "78.0000000"
    }
  ]
]
```

el resultado que deseo obtener es el siguiente,eh tratado de realizarlo de muchas formas pero no eh podido lograrlo.

```
    [
  [
    {
      "l_grupo": "F003",
      "total": 543,
      "desde": 45,
      "hasta": 47
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "45",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "375.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "46",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "52.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "47",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "116.0000000"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "l_grupo": "B003",
      "total": 406
      "desde": 15,
      "hasta": 21
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "21",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "35.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "18",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "88.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "15",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "93.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "16",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "112.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "17",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "78.0000000"
    }
  ]
]
```

Espero alguein me pueda ayudar, de ante mano muchas gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con ayuda de recorrer todos los elementos y los elementos anidados a excepción del elemento 1, podemos ir guardando los valores `n_comp` en un array para poder usar el `Math.max.apply` o `Math.min.apply` que nos devuelve el mínimo o máximo valor de un array simple. [Revisa esto para que tengas más información](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985341/get-max-and-min-value-from-array-in-javascript)

```js
var array = [
  [
    {
      "l_grupo": "F003",
      "total": 543
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "45",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "375.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "46",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "52.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "01",
      "n_seri": "F003",
      "n_comp": "47",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "116.0000000"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "l_grupo": "B003",
      "total": 406
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "21",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "35.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "18",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "88.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "15",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "93.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "16",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "112.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0",
      "c_comp": "03",
      "n_seri": "B003",
      "n_comp": "17",
      "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
      "k_mone": "0",
      "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
      "s_tota": "78.0000000"
    }
  ]
];

var new_array = [];
for ( var element = 0; element < array.length; element++ ) {
  var values = [];
  for ( var element_adicional = 1; element_adicional < array[element].length; element_adicional++ ) {
    values.push(parseInt(array[element][element_adicional].n_comp));
    //values.push(parseFloat(array[element][element_adicional].n_comp).toFixed(2)); si te interesa conservar decimales
  }
  array[element][0]["desde"] = Math.min.apply(Math,values);;
  array[element][0]["hasta"] = Math.max.apply(Math,values);;
  //new_array.push();
}

console.log(array);
```